# How to get the text of a hover/popover in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When I mouse over a button (using ActionChains), there is text displayed
as a hover/popover. I'm trying to get the text of the popover. As you can
see in the xml below, the text is "Auto Deferral End scheduled for
02/20/2019 11:35:42 PM". I'm unable to find the syntax to get this text.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-md btn-lg pull-right" 
ng- disabled="" ng-click="openDeferralPopUp()" style="height: 29px; width:
90%; padding: 0px; margin-left: 2px;" popover="Auto Deferral End scheduled
for 02/20/2019 11:35:42 PM" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-append-to-
body="true" popover-class="popover-auto-state-class">
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a solution:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("your xpath").get_attribute('popover')
```

Comment: Just about to post essentially that :) Now is this enough to **prove** that the popover actually appears in a way that makes sense? Maybe not, but it's probably good enough.